# How to "zoom out" screen windows, everything looks too big?

Tags: linux, gnome, linux-mint, gnome3, eclipse

I bought new laptop Dell Inspiron and first thing I installed Linux Mint and Eclipse for Java development. But I didn't like the look of Eclipse, everything just looks too big on the screen. Half of the space is taken by the tabs and menus, no room for editor, also the font is too big.

I would like to shrink the whole screen if possible, to have smaller fonts and tabs etc., but the display is on the maximum resolution already (1366x768).

How can I do this? I'm quite new to Linux and gnome, but I'm sure there is a simple solution to my problem.

Comment: Does the output of `xdpyinfo` indicate that you are using the screen resolution you expected?

Comment: yes it shows correct resolution

Comment: And what about the reported *physical* screen *size*? (actually directly related to the [screen *resolution*](http://enwp.org/Dots_per_inch) (pixel density, not pixel area), should be given along with the pixel area size in `xdpyinfo`; resolution/density being given in the `resolution` line). You may have an issue where the resolution is wrongly guessed, and even if it's correctly guessed, you may want to decrease it, so that the programs (at least the ones respecting this setting...) look smaller.

Comment: actually I found the solution. [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1465712). stackexchange allows to post my own answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1465712). It recommends creating a new compact GTK style by pasting this into `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "gtkcompact" {
GtkButton::default_border={0,0,0,0}
GtkButton::default_outside_border={0,0,0,0}
GtkButtonBox::child_min_width=0
GtkButtonBox::child_min_heigth=0
GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_x=0
GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_y=0
GtkMenu::vertical-padding=1
GtkMenuBar::internal_padding=0
GtkMenuItem::horizontal_padding=4
GtkToolbar::internal-padding=0
GtkToolbar::space-size=0
GtkOptionMenu::indicator_size=0
GtkOptionMenu::indicator_spacing=0
GtkPaned::handle_size=4
GtkRange::trough_border=0
GtkRange::stepper_spacing=0
GtkScale::value_spacing=0
GtkScrolledWindow::scrollbar_spacing=0
GtkTreeView::vertical-separator=0
GtkTreeView::horizontal-separator=0
GtkTreeView::fixed-height-mode=TRUE
GtkWidget::focus_padding=0
}
class "GtkWidget" style "gtkcompact"
```

Answer (score 1):

Font sizing is not all controlled in one place.  You should be able to control the fonts Gnome uses for the desktop environment by using the menu "System > Preferences > Appearance".   There is a "Fonts" tab in the dialog box that comes up.

The font settings for Eclipse are under the menu item "Window > Preferences".   In the dialog box, select "General > Appearance > Fonts and Colors".